# Building a Digg clone using WordPress?

Tags: custom-post-types, links, buddypress

I am thinking of building a site similar to **Digg.com** (the old version). I think the best way in my case is to make a *custom post type* for the links and then use a a plugin such as *TDO Mini Forms* or *One Click Post* for front end posting.
As for voting I'm thinking of using the *Vote it up* plugin.

There are 3 main problems I need help with:

1. An important part of my site will be images. When submitting a new link I need the ability to automaticly grab images from the submitted the site that the user can crop to predefined size and then attach to the post. There is a plugin for Hotaru CMS (http://forums.hotarucms.org/showthread.php?559-Post-Images-0.6&highlight=post+images) that does exactly what I want but I don't know how to port it over to wordpress and then implement it in submission form.
2. **(EDIT: Answered, see below)** The *Vote it up* plugin doesn't sort the posts based on how many votes they have. I want one page with all the new links and one with the 'popular' links were all links with a specific minimum number of votes will be. For example, when a link gets 10 or more votes it is moved from the 'new' page to the 'popular' page. There are some functions on the plugin page, I'm not sure how to use them: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/vote-it-up/other_notes/
3. I need a vote button that users can put on their blogs or websites for their readers to submit and vote on their posts. Something similar to the Digg button you can find all over the web.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *@patrikp* What's your skill level? PHP dev, designer comfortable with template tags or end user? Also where do you envision the image links pointing to? Flickr or something else?

Comment: I have some basic PHP skills but it's nothing to brag about. I'm pretty comfortable with designing templates.

The images will be loaded from the submitted page. Lets say you submit a blogpost with an image in it, then that image will be loaded. Check out http://japansoc.com (built with Hotaru CMS, not Wordpress) and I think you will understand what I mean.

Comment: What exactly do you want help with?

Comment: @Shubhakarman - I changed the whole text instead of answering with a comment, it did get a little messy without linebreaks :)

Comment: If you're looking for something PHP and MySQL and doing a DIGG clone w/o being fixed on WP, you might look for Drupal. There's something avail already AFAIK since about 1-2 years.

Comment: @hakre - I know about most of the digg-like scripts and drupal + the drigg module seems to be good. however, I'm want to do this in Wordpress.

Comment: *@Patrik:* Well then, maybe there is a drupal-plugin for wordpress? Drupal is pretty modular and has a single, central command interface (router), so this could be possible. That would be drupal in wordpress then and not a-digg-like in wordpress, tough :)

Answer (score 3):

I have seen a similar question on http://stackoverflow.com a few days ago .
I think my answer may not help you .But There are some other examples mentioned which were built like digg already on wordpress platform .
http://nestdev.com is the best one I have ever saw .

(Sorry If My answer doesn't fit to the question .I didn't find comment option here for  this question.May be my reputation level is not enough to use the option to comment.SO I have post this as answer)

Comment: Yes, I have read that thread too. I think I saw a forum post somewhere on how to make that possible with wordpress and the vote it up plugin, will post it if I find it.

Comment: Here is a function which add posibilities to sort post on index page by vote. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-vote-it-up-show-top-voted-post-in-index-page

Answer (score 3):

I've been working on a "Recommended Links" WP/BuddyPress plugin that essentially does the same thing... would be happy to share the code if you're interested, although its still only half finished. Link adding and up/downvoting are pretty functional, but I haven't done the commenting functions yet... Still, feel free to build off of anything thats useful in it.

http://goldenapplesdesign.com/projects/recommended-links-plugin-for-wordpress/

I ended up creating two whole new tables, because I saw it potentially overwhelming the posts and comments tables, and when I started working on it (pre-WP3.0) because of the sheer volume of links and comments, it was easier to add new admin pages than try to work with custom post types. Now, I'd recommend using a custom post type, and at some point I'll rewrite what I have to do it that way.

Comment: You have come a long way with that, great work!

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify if you want to build it using free solutions alone, or have budget for this. So this one is not free, but seems like a good fit.

Theme that powers [WordPress Vote](http://wpvote.com/) (Digg-like site for content about WP) had been released for sale in more generic version as [Nominate](http://prothemedesign.com/themes/nominate-for-wordpress/)

PS grabbing full images from third party site is a practice I'd stay away from. Copyright, licenses and such.

Answer (score 0):

I know I COULD get downvotes for not answering the question directly and proposing another platform.... but hey... if a customer asked me for a Digg clone I would install Pligg (http://www.pligg.com/) since... well... that is the digg clone...

Comment: If you know you could get downvotes, doesn't that give you an indicator that maybe the answer is out of place on a WordPress Answers site? Just sayin...

Comment: Have you ever been in a large meeting with a lot of managers and you, a technical guy, was asked something and you wanted to tell the honest truth (for you) but it was not really career improving by making such a statement in this meeting at that time? Well... sometimes you have to suffer because of being technical and not political and then have nightmares because of it for years after :) In this case, really, if a customer comes to me with this question as above I would give him exact this answer (although I loose business because I can not make a WP site here)

Comment: Downvote. While this info may be pertinent to helping the OP clone digg, it's not a pertinent answer for a WordPress question. A better place for this 'answer' would have been as a comment on the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [BuddyPress Links](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/buddypress-links/).

Comment: Are you affiliated with the plugin or the developer? If so, you have to state so.